# Upstairs/The floors above

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, idiomatic-language

**Will:** *Two men have been found dead upstairs.*

If will is on the 6th floor of an office building, while the two men have been found dead on the 8th and 9th floor respectively, could I use "upstairs" then or would it be taken to mean the 7th floor?

If "upstairs" doesn't work, what else would be natural to say? Would this work:

**Will:** *Two men have been found dead on the floors above us.*

?

Comment: "Upstairs" is fine to mean any of the floors above you.  You'd say "directly above" to mean only one floor up.

Comment: In this context I might say something like "**two/three floors up**", but I'm not sure how common that is.